# GIS shapefile of corporate headquarters located in the US?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, shapefile, data

I am conducting MSA (Metropolitan Statistical Area) level analysis where I am tracking the number of corporate headquarters in the top 50 MSAs from 2000 to 2014. I am looking for a shapefile like [this](https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/4f4e4a19e4b07f02db6061c3) for both 2000 and 2014 (or close to 2000 and 2014). Has anyone used such shapefiles and if so, did you find them online or have to construct them on your own? If there is a shapefile for all corporate headquarters in the US for 2000 and 2014, I can do select by location with a MSA shapefile. Or if I can get a list of corporate headquarters by MSA for 2000 and 2014, I can just join the data file to the MSA shapefile.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  As a new user, please be sure to take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).  Unfortunately, this question is less about GIS than about locating data, and the question itself is more of a discussion invitation or survey with multiple elements, which doesn't fit well with the Focused Question/Best Answer model used here.